# Best way to schedule an application on raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I'm running a raspberry pi, and I would like to run a specific application (qbittorrent-nox) between 00:00 and 12:00.

Currently the service is scheduled using systemd, but I don't know what the best way is to schedule it.
I am looking for a solution which does not depend on the time I start the raspberry pi.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: If you want to use systemd have a look at `man systemd.timer`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the executable is ~/bin/qbittorrent-nox as the two examples I have seen use that (sorry do not run it myself). If not shout if you cannot change these commands.

I would use the Linux [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) system to schedule two jobs.  One to start every day of the year and one to kill the job every day of the year two hours later.

Note midnight is a nightmare for scheduling as many an argument of what day of the week midnight is on has been seen.  I like one minute past (00:01) or even one second past (00:00:01) as it stops any cloudy minds as to the day the job starts on :)

To generate CRONTAB entries, I use [Crontab Generator dot org](https://crontab-generator.org/) though others are available.

So to start the task we have an entry like this:

```
 * 0 * * * ~/bin/qbittorrent-nox >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And to kill the task you can try:

```
* 2 * * * pkill -9 -fu "$(whoami)" 'qbittorrent-nox' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

These should be set up in CRON for the same user (normally PI or ROOT) and there are many many examples of setting up this for the Pi such as:

- [The raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md) documentation
- [Pi my life up](https://pimylifeup.com/cron-jobs-and-crontab/)
- Etc etc.